# How to workaround too often Redux updates in a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux

I have a browser application with the React-Redux architecture. Many events occur in the application (e.g. timeouts, web socket incoming messages, web workers messages, XHR responses, etc.). Each event emits a Redux action that changes the Redux store that causes a React render.

The problem is that the events occur so often that React doesn't have enough time to render the UI (for example, an event occurs every 5ms (or more often) and React takes 10ms to render the UI). It makes the whole page stop responding because the render process doesn't stop (it always has something to render) and the browser has no time to draw the DOM or handle a DOM event.

What are the approaches or ready solutions to solve this problem considering that I can reduce neither the events frequency nor the React render time?

Comment: I'm not sure if every data updates will change the value? If it's not, maybe u can try `memoization`? https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization

Comment: @tekminewe I use React.PureComponent and I mean the updates that change the values. Anyway it's the "reduce React render time" approach which is not always suitable.

Comment: Have you consider using debounce function concept to solve this issue? Only pass changes to redux store if a certain interval time has passed, else just ignore the response from the backend.

Comment: @remelkabir I thought about it but have never used it. Please post an answer describing this technique.

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086
this might give you an insight on how to use it.

Comment: @remelkabir I'm familiar with the debounce technique, I wonder how people use it in React-Redux applications to solve the problem I've described

Comment: You can set up a property `updatedAt` and check to see if something like 3 seconds passed, every time new data arrives and there is a 3 seconds window update the property and the store otherwise just return the current state

Comment: My apologies, I confused myself between debounce and throttling. In your case throttling will solve the issue. you can set a delay of time that you desire for the state to be updated. Make a delay on your action that updates your state. Only fire that action with the latest payload after a certain amount of time interval.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the state from a websocket message, record the time and only do another update if a certain amount of time has passed since then.

In this example the state is updated only if 1000ms have passed since the last update:

```
client.onUpdate(data => {        
    if (!this.lastUpdate || 
        new Date().getTime() - this.lastUpdate.getTime() > 1000) {
        this.setState({ data });
        this.lastUpdate = new Date();
    }
})
```

Comment: Apparently the state is stored in a React component (not in the Redux store) in your example. But I've got the idea, thank you.

Comment: @Finesse yes this is for react not redux but the idea is the same. I also just realized that lastUpdate should not be stored in the state since the view doesn't depend on it and it's async

Answer (score 0):

You can simply debounce your handler.

*debounced function* means it can be invoked only once in X period of time.

For the sake of the example I will not implement the details of debouncing a function, but rather use `lodash`.

```
// function that handles the server update.
const serverUpdateHandler = (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SERVER_UPDATE
  })
}
// create a new function that is debounced. aka - will invoke after 250 milliseconds after the lace invokation
const debouncedHandler = _.debounce(serverUpdateHandler,250);
// pass socket.io the debounced function
socket.on('server-update',debouncedHandler)
```